# в чём разница между эрративом и графоном?

Tags: значение

(текст для пропуска проверки)...

Comment: Вопрос не конкретен, в нём не обозначена проблема автора.

Answer (score 1):

Графон — умышленное искажение орфографической нормы, отражающее индивидуальные или диалектные отклонения от фонетической нормы.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Графон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD)

Эррати́в (от лат. errare в значении «ошибаться») — слово или выражение, подвергнутое нарочному искажению носителем языка, владеющим литературной нормой, для придания особого эффекта.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Эрратив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Разница: отражает индивидуальные или диалектные отклонения | используется для придания особого эффекта.